# Real examples with とて

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm studying the usage of とて. I think I understand its meaning: even, even if. However, although I've read that とて is quite an archaic particle (not used very often in daily conversations), the very few examples I can find online when looking for this piece of grammar seem to be very casual, so I doubt if they are actually good examples that fit the reality.

Then, if possible, could you please provide real examples of とて so I can see how is it used normally?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your situation:

**1,000近いrepがある私とて実用的な例文を探すのが難しい**

*Even I, who has near 1,000 reps, struggle to find a practical example*

---

One typical set phrase I see often is **私とて黙っちゃいない** .

Although it's rather antiquated as you said, it's still borderline "normal" even by today's standards to simply replace with **だって** if you wish:

**Even a rich person can't buy time**

- 金持ち だって 時間は 買えない
- 金持ち とて 時間は 買えない

**Even I can't do it (assuming "I" am a capable person)**

- 私 だって できない
- 私 とて できない

So it's more about **when** to use とて over other options such as だって. I'd use it in a serious situation to add drama, which can be said for many "archaic" phrases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. About 私とて黙っちゃいない, could you please tell me in which kind of contexts did you see that set phrase? I would like to learn how to use it properly, so it would be great if you could give me an example.